# airflow operator to use gcloud beta dataproc commands

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anyone know if it exists an Airflow operator that could do what do the gcloud beta commands?
I'm trying to launch a Spark job on a GKE cluster. The gcloud beta commands works, but it is not the case using `DataprocSparkOperator`.

With this operator, the job keeps turning but the driver pod is not instantiated, but it works doing the gcloud command referenced here : https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/dataproc-gke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be completely honest, I believe that Airflow is not intended to run `gcloud` commands. If there is no operator, that you can use it's better to use Google API in conduction with `PythonOperator`.

If you really want to use `gcloud` commands, you'll need to install `gcloud` SDK in your Airflow instance:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#silent  . It's quite heavy, so if you have Airflow as a Service it will take longer to deploy it.

After all you'll need to authorize - there is `service-account` way which might be optimal for you: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account .
You'll have to put `service-account` in some safe place, e.g `HDFS` (if you have a cluster). For local purposes it can be stored locally.

If you're done with authorization just use `BashOperator` to do what you want - you have `gcloud` in your Airflow installed.